# problems with booting Ubuntu 14.04 after fresh installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, encryption

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 on my PC (the 64-bit version), on which I had Ubuntu 12.04 before that, and I have problems with booting.

The installation was just fine, I chose to encrypt my hard drive. The problem is that when I start my computer, the screen remains black and then goes to stand by as when there were no signal, i.e., as when the computer is off. Then I switch off the computer by long-pressing the start button and after that switch it on again. This time I get the following menu:

> GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-9ubuntu1.6
>
> Ubuntu  
>   Advanced options for Ubuntu  
>   Memory test (memtest86+) 
>   Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)
>
> Use the  and ↆ keys to select which entry is >highlighted  
>   Pres enter to boot the selected OS, 'e' to edit the >commands before booting or 'c' for a command line.

When I choose the Ubuntu option and press Enter, everything is fine. I get the screen where I enter my encryption password and then the log-in screen. So, eventually I manage to boot my system but the manual shut down by long-pressing the start key is not the way it should be done. Restart from the settings key (upper right corner) shows the same problem.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? Perhaps I have done something wrong during the installation process? I installed just few days ago, so, if the solution is complicated, I could reinstall taking into account any peace of advice you give.

P.S. about my computer:  
RAM: 4GB  
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4  
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NVD9  
Hard disk: 500GB (only 1% is used)

Edit (in response to the_Seppi):  
the command `sudo lshw -c video` gives

```
*-display  
     description: VGA compatible controller  
     product: GF119 [GeForce GT 610]  
     vendor: NVIDIA Corporation  
     physical id: 0  
     bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0  
     version: a1  
     width: 64 bits  
     clock: 33MHz  
     capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom  
     configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0  
     resources: irq:30 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:e8000000-e9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff  
*-display
     description: Display controller
     product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
     vendor: Intel Corporation
     physical id: 2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0  
     version: 09
     width: 64 bits
     clock: 33MHz
     capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
     resources: irq:31 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Comment: It might be a graphics issue. Please add the output of `sudo lshw -c video` as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Tried boot options like nomodeset, etc? fyi - if the kernel's at all responsive, then instead of "pulling the plug" you could try ctrl-alt-SysReq REISUB